# Show or Hide information displayed by click

Tags: javascript, html

Following is My Code. It consist of three buttons and a display screen.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="fun" >
Display Screen<input type="textfield" name="ans" value="">
<br>
<input type="button" value="1" onClick="document.fun.ans.value+='1'">
<input type="button" value="hide">
<input type="button" value="show">


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently when you press 1 it will show 1 on display screen. 
I would like to implement a function so that if you click hide and then press 1 nothing will get display. If you press show and press 1 then 1 will display on screen.

Possible Approach is to just disable the 1 button if u click hide but i still want user to be able to click the button after pressing hide just not  display anything.

I am new to JS so please forgive if this is a bad question.

Comment: take a look at my answer I think it is what you are looking for...hopefully it helps!

Comment: Do you mean it shouldn't append anything on click of "1" if hide was already clicked (and append 1 on click of "1" if show was already clicked)? Or hide text field completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wrap all the js in `<script>` to be able to work with vars.

```
<script>
    var hide = 0;
    function appendChar(){
        if(hide==0){
            document.fun.ans.value+='1';
        }
    }

</script>
```

Then we have to modify the html:

```
<input type="button" value="1" onClick="appendChar()">
<input type="button" value="hide" onclick="hide=1;">
<input type="button" value="show" onclick="hide=0;">
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of showing and hiding an element using javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="fun" >
Display Screen<input id="ans" type="textfield" name="ans" value="">
<br>
<input type="button" value="1" onClick="document.fun.ans.value='1'">
<input type="button" value="hide" onclick="hide()">
<input type="button" value="show" onclick="show()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function hide()
{
   document.getElementById("ans").style.display = "none";
}
function show()
{
   document.getElementById("ans").value = '';
   document.getElementById("ans").style.display = "inline-block";
}
</script>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```